# Ember.js nested property calculations returning undefined

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm having an issue with two levels of calculated properties. I'm a bit new to ember so would appreciate some pointers.

The basic problem is that there are two levels of calculated properties - one at the order level and one at the item level. The order level is dependent on the calculation on the item.

After binding to the form - the item level calculation works great and the form is updated as I change the quantity. The order total however does not seem to calculate at all. Am I missing something in the property dependencies?

```
App.Order = DS.Model.extend({
    items: DS.hasMany('item', { async: true } ),
    payment_cash: DS.attr('number'),
    payment_card: DS.attr('number'),
    payment_credit: DS.attr('number'),
    balance: DS.attr('number'),
    total: function() {
      return this.get('items').reduce(function(value,lineItem) {
        value += lineItem.get('total');  
      });
    }.property("items.@each.total"),
    itemCount: function() {
      return this.get('items').reduce(function(value,lineItem) {
        value += lineItem.get('quantity');  
      });
    }.property("items.@each.quantity"),
});

App.Item = DS.Model.extend({
  order: DS.belongsTo('item'),
  product: DS.belongsTo('product'),
  quantity: DS.attr('number'),
  adjustment: DS.attr('number'),
  total: function() {
    return this.get('product.price') * this.get('quantity')
  }.property('product.price', 'quantity' )
});


App.Product = DS.Model.extend( {
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  description: DS.attr('string'),
  price: DS.attr('number'),
  imagePath: DS.attr('string')
});
```

Comment: looks pretty good, have you thrown some logs into the total's?  Are they being called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `reduce` function is not `return`ing anything. Try this:

```
total: function() {
  return this.get('items').reduce( function(value, lineItem) {
    return value += lineItem.get('total');  
  }, 0 );
}.property("items.@each.total"),

itemCount: function() {
  return this.get('items').reduce( function(value, lineItem) {
    return value += lineItem.get('quantity');  
  } , 0);
}.property("items.@each.quantity"),
```

Comment: Well done. Thanks for that. I've been going round in circles for days.